# How to use TopLevelItem (MenuItemRole)

Tags: wpf, xaml

By changing the background to blue for [this sample](https://github.com/mesta1/Simple-wpf-styles/blob/master/csharp/resources/menu.xaml), I was able to figure out what styles for the other roles of `MenuItem` could do:

1. `TopLevelHeader`

[image][image]

2. `SubmenuHeader`

[image][image]

3. `SubmenuItem`

[image][image]

But changing the style for `TopLevelItem` didn't appear to have any effect, so I'm wondering if anyone would give an example of how it can be used.

Comment: You obviously don't have a top level item, which is a top level `MenuItem` without child items. When a `MenuItem` has submenu items, then the `TopLevelHeaderTemplateKey` or `SubmenuHeaderTemplateKey` applies. Only if the item has no children, the `SubmenuItemTemplateKey` or `TopLevelItemTemplateKey` applies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BionicCode commented

> You obviously don't have a top level item, which is a top level `MenuItem` without child items. When a `MenuItem` has submenu items, then the `TopLevelHeaderTemplateKey` or `SubmenuHeaderTemplateKey` applies. Only if the item has no children, the `SubmenuItemTemplateKey` or `TopLevelItemTemplateKey` applies.